# Is there a way to store the names of each label clicked simultaneously in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

![enter image description here][1]I have created a java swing application which detects label clicks and searches the linked list for objects that match the label name.

Now I have already implemented this assuming only one label is clicked.

However let us say if a user clicks 5 labels at a time I want to capture all 5 simultaneously in order to do a comparison.

Now I would like to clarify one more thing that the labels are generated dynamically based on the number of records in the linked list.For example if the linked list has only 5 author fields,then only 5 labels are created.

Comment: And I can't get how user can click 5 labels simultaneously. In my opinion he will click it one by one. Maybe I don't get something.

Comment: Ok wrong choice of word,I will upload a screenshot to make things clear

Comment: Right now if I click one label and click update,I will get a list of files related to this user.

Comment: I want to click more than one label and when I click update ,I want to store all the 3 clicks so that I can find a union of files of these 3 users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is what you are looking for...

```
final List<String> labelNames = new ArrayList<String>();
MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() instanceof JLabel){
      labelNames.add(((JLabel) e.getSource()).getText());
    }
  }
};
JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
label1.addMouseListener(listener);
JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
label1.addMouseListener(listener);
JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
label1.addMouseListener(listener);
```

Comment: well the code I posted will collect text from labels that user clicks. No matter how many times he does it. Isn't this what you need?

Comment: Exactly,this was what I wanted.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing "how" the labels are displayed or "how" you are capturing the mouse clicks or "how" you a search the list, my minor suggestion would be to add a "delay" between the clicks and then search, allowing the user time to make a selection, assuming you wanted the search to occur in real time (ie, without the need to press another button to start the search)

Obviously you would also need to take into consideration what would happen if the user changed there minds, how would you stop and restart the search, but without any actual idea of how you are doing this, it's impossible to make a suggestion.

Basically I would use a [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) set to reasonable delay (say 500 milliseconds to a second) that would, when the timer fires, start the search.

On each "click" of an label, I would simply restart the timer, inserting a new delay.

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot.This is actually a visualization of an svn repository log file.

Comment: I read an xml file and stored all values to a linked list.Now each value of the linked list is shown as a label.